# AUTORUN.inf not working

Tags: autorun, inf, compact-disc

Could sombody please tell me why my Autorun.inf is not working when i burn it to CD rom..?

I have checked the fille names and they all exist?

```
[autorun]
open="VTS\TREADSTONE LT\TREADSTONE LT.bat"
icon="VTS\TREADSTONE LT\ICO\TREADSTONE.ico"
label="Treadstone Installation"
shell\Install\command="VTS\TREADSTONE LT\TREADSTONE LT.bat"
```

Comment: Note that, as far as I know, Windows has moved away from auto-running `autorun.inf` without prompt because this was an immensely easy and effective way to spread viruses. Also, this question may be better suited on [su].

Comment: i followed all the instructions on the online tutorials they dont seem that hard??

Comment: Many organizations disable autorun using group policy since it is a requirement in various security standards. Numerous tools also exist that will make the needed registry changes to stop autorun and IIRC Microsoft may have made some of those changes with an update in the last year or two. You are probably better off just creating 'setup.bat' in the root of your cd to make it obvious what a user should click.